# Run some code when the app updates in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, updating, background-task

I'm having trouble when updating my app while handling every version of it. If I could run some code when the app finishes the update process, it'll be great.

Is there anyway to do that? maybe with a background task? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

To run code after your app updates, you can use a background task with the `ServicingComplete` trigger - https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br224839